# Can we use the indefinite pronoun “someone” as a possessive pronoun “someone’s”? (not only as a possessive determiner)

Tags: pronouns, possessive-pronouns, indefinite-pronouns

We can use personal pronouns in the possessive case:

1. The book is mine. / Mine is missing.
2. The shirt is yours. / Yours is missing.

Can we use the indefinite pronoun *someone* like this?

3. The book is someone’s. / Someone’s is missing.

So can we use *someone’s* as a standalone possessive **pronoun**, not just as a possessive **determiner** like:

4. This is someone’s book. / Someone’s book is missing.

Comment: "Someone" is a compound determinative, not a pronoun. Yes: "The book is someone's".

Comment: @BillJ Or even: *This books isn’t mine, so it must be someone else’s.*

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'someone' *in the* possessive case.

> In the crowd, I accidentally stood on someone's foot.

Comment: but here it is adjective not pronoun

Comment: @Hadman No: in "someone's foot" "someone's" is a (compound) determinative functioning as a genitive fused determiner-head meaning "some person's foot". It can also stand alone as in "I can't trace the owner, but it must be someone's", meaning it must belong to some person"

Comment: it means someone and one pronouns do not have possesive form as a pronoun.when we show possession with these pronoun they become determiner right.

Comment: Wrong. Who says it's adjective not pronoun? Pronouns do have possessive forms: _his, her(s), its, our(s), your(s), their(s), my, mine_. The fact that they're possessive and modify something like all possessives does not make them adjectives.  Clearly you shouldn't be studying parts of speech without adequate information.

Answer (score -1):

It makes sense to me that "ones" and "someones" are legitimate possessive pronouns and do not need the apostrophe.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).